# What event to use, when returning back to previous activity that is not finished?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I have a `VideosList` activity, from which I go to `VideoDetail`. I use `startActivity` method, but I don't finish the previous activity.

Now user goes to `VideoDetail` activity and likes the video. Then he goes back to `VideosList` to see another video.

However, I want to reload videos in that `VideosActivity`, so that updated information of likes count and other data would be shown.

What method should I override?

Comment: Use `startActivityForResult()` and you do not need to reload data just to increment a like count .

Comment: onResume clear the list and reload the new updated list

Comment: @ADM it's a good idea, but also he could do a silent reload of more data if needed. Anyway I'm agree with the usage of `startActivityForResult()`.